# SQL Server 2014 Developer on Windows 10?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, windows-10

Has anyone tried to use SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition (64 bit) on Windows 10 yet? I have a Lenovo G50-45 laptop that came with Windows 8.1 and I have the option to upgrade, but I don't want to shoot my working setup in the tail by upgrading -- unless it is pretty certain to be successful and reasonably bump free. I guess I'm hoping to hear from someone who took the plunge who can report unparalleled success (or abject failure) to help nudge me off the fence on upgrading Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2014 works on Windows 10 just fine. Some upgrade paths, though, will move all your apps and services to Windows.old (this happened to me one upgrade out of 4 or 5), so be careful and take the usual backups and other precautions. Thankfully, reinstalling SQL Server is not an extremely elaborate process.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to do a little research on this "Windows.old" business beforehand I suppose. I like to know (more or less) what I'm up against in any upgrade scenario. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Stephen this issue is described [here](http://serverfault.com/a/34866/23215) (but regarding a different OS upgrade path), though it's not clear what criteria lead to the issue. The KB showing how to revert to the old operating system () if you need to are listed in [KB #971760](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971760), and I think will still be relevant for Windows 10, but also see [this article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2960692/windows/how-to-uninstall-windows-10-and-go-back-to-windows-7-or-8.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is `known issue` with `Windows 10` not with SQL Server as such. What happens is when you upgrade your system to windows 10 from previous version and you either have SQL Server 2012/SQL Server 2014 and you restart your windows machine the SQL Server services will not come online **even if startup mode is automatic.**

You would have to manually go and start the SQL Server services from SCCM or Services.msc, I would recommend you always manage services from SSCM. I am not sure whether MS is working on it. This is all assuming there is no issue with SQL Server.

**Solution:**

There is a workaround though, you can delay the start of SQL Server service by selecting `Automatic (delayed start)`. Go to `services.msc` locate SQL Server services right click and select properties. Below page will appear. In `startup` select `Automatic(Delayed Start)`.

[image]

After selecting above **restart your windows machine**

**NOTE:** Due to delayed start SQL Server service might take some time to come online but eventually it will.

There is similar issue mentioned in [this msdn thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bb5f2199-f283-4249-a029-53978d637148/sql-service-stops-working-after-windows-10-upgrade?forum=sqldatabaseengine)